# no package 'librsvg-2.0' found

Tags: apt, package-management

I am trying to install GNOME mahjong
When I hit
./configure && make && make install
It returns a condition left of a program that is remaining to install
no package ' librsvg-2.0' found
Is there any command to install it?
I tried sudo apt-get install librsvg-2.0
Didn't work

Also I tried successful
sudo apt-get install librsvg2-bin and installed successfully. BUT
still appeared, "no package  'librsvg-2.0 ' found"

Comment: When you are building things from source, it is almost always the `-dev` package that needs to be installed - in this case, it looks like that would be `librsvg2-dev`

Comment: What was wrong with installing [binary package](https://packages.ubuntu.com/focal/gnome-mahjongg) as simple as `sudo apt-get install gnome-mahjongg` ?

Comment: It worked with sudo apt -get install gnome-mahjongg @N0rbert

Answer (score 1):

I installed it from repository as N0rbert suggested:

```
sudo apt-get install gnome-mahjongg
```